# Peter Norvig's regular expression compiler from Udacity course rewritten in Racket

Tags: regex, racket

These days I have took Peter Norvig's Udacity course CS212: DESIGN OF COMPUTER PROGRAMS.
Unfortunately, the course is all in Python so, for the sake of learning, I wrote the equivalent code in Racket for regex compiler given in unit 3 of that course.

You can see my code here: http://codepad.org/8x0rMXOi

Now, what's bothering me is that Mr. Norvig's original code in Python is somewhat shorter than mine. :( But ok, I'm just beginner in Racket, and that is expected. But I wonder if some Racket expert can shorten my code, so that Racket code become shorter than original Norvig's Python code?

Comment: This question seems appropriate for Code Review

Comment: Would this question be a better fit for <a href="http://codereview.stackexchange.com/">Code Review</a>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few tips.

The ormap-expression in:

```
 (define (in-chars? c chars)
   (ormap (lambda (ch) (equal? c ch)) (string->list chars)))
```

can be written as

```
   (memv c (string->list chars))
```

The if-epression in

```
(define (match pattern text)
  (define remainders (pattern text))
  (if (not (set-empty? remainders))
      (substring text 0 (- (string-length text)
                           (string-length (argmin string-length 
                                                  (set->list remainders)))))
      #f))
```

can be written as

```
 (and (not (set-empty? remainders))
      (substring ...)
```

However your function are small and to the point, so I wouldn't change much.

A more convenient syntax for manipulating strings would make
it easier to read and write string manipulation programs. Some years ago I made an attempt and wrote a concat macro.

I used it to implement Norvig's spelling checker (his original article might interest you). The resulting spelling checker and the concat macro is explained here

http://blog.scheme.dk/2007/04/writing-spelling-corrector-in-plt.html

Update: I have written an updated version of the spell checker.
        The concat macro is makes simple string manipulation shorter.

https://github.com/soegaard/this-and-that/blob/master/spell-checker.rkt

Comment: Another approach of `in-chars?`: use a `for/or`, since strings are iterable.  `(for/or ([ch chars]) (equal? c ch))`.